# FBI Expanded Background Check

Tags: new-job, background-check

Asking a question of people who are more versed than me in FBI background checks.

I've just received a job offer in finance—perfect job for me!—and am now being asked to complete a pro forma FBI background check. I'm wondering if the following incident will show up and if so, whether it would be problematic:

In 2019, I was enrolled in a STEM program at an Ivy League school (not mentioning this for clout but to indicate level of pressure), enrolled in several Ph.D.-level courses, doing research with a professor, and teaching an undergraduate course. The stress was incredible; there were many other non-professional stressors as well. In the end, the constant, overwhelming stress (in addition to diagnosed M.D.D.) led me to some bizarre, nonviolent behavior with my roommate. My roommate became concerned and called the police, who he believed would take me to the hospital for the night. At some point, I tried to push a police officer, who was blocking my exit, out of the way so that I could leave; they promptly tackled me to the ground, handcuffed me, and drove me to the hospital. I was not charged with any offense. I had no mental health issues (besides M.D.D.) before this and have had none since.

I'm assuming there must be some kind of paperwork somewhere about this event; would it appear in an FBI background check? If so, is this something I could explain?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for a federal job, contractor or civilian? I've had a clearance for contractor position but am not sure what "expanded FBI background check" means. In the application form, you can explain some answers. But if denied, it is super hard to find out why.

Comment: This is a part of your life, you cannot change that. Don't let it hold you back. Proceed with the application, see what happens, and deal with anything that comes up as and when you need to do so. Don't assume the worst and pull out, because you will just end up in the same situation next time.

Comment: Yeah, there's the background check the FBI does on its own candidates which is more stringent, I assume he means this kind though https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/fbi-background-checks-how-do-work-sajid-patel/

Comment: @mxyzplk is correct about what I'm referring to as an FBI background check. Sorry for any ambiguity.

Comment: @siegfried- Were you assigned some sort of contact to answer questions about the SF86 (through e-qip) you are filling out?  You can also contact the police department if you have a concern about the event in question.  Unless you were formally charged with something, there likely isn't a record, but you must answer ALL questions truthfully on the SF86

Comment: In what jurisdiction are you in? In California, the background checks are strictly regulated based on the type of job you're applying for.

Comment: @Donald I was at no point charged with an offense. It's difficult to tell and AFAIK there is no hard line, but I think this event was a "detention" rather than an "arrest"—the difference being that charges were not involved. I don't believe I filled out an SF86, but there was one application question asking if I'd ever been convicted or gone through an ARD (I had not).

Comment: @StephanBranczyk To protect my privacy, I'd like to keep my location private. I will say I'm in a state that forbids employers from rescinding a job offer on the basis of an arrest-without-conviction. Again, per my above comment, it's not clear in the first place that this was an arrest.

Comment: @siegfried- I am confused. *You said mxyzplk was correct.*  If that is the case you should be filling out a SF86.  You must provide accurate information.  An informal incident like this could be discovered, having never experienced any negative interaction with a police officer (other than a traffic citation), I wouldn't be able to speak to it.  I can only talk about the SF-86, it asks specific questions, they are often *yes* or *no* questions.  They are also specific with regards, how long ago, those events can be (i.e. a traffic citation more than $400 within the last 3 years).

Comment: @siegfried, Then, you've got your answer. Don't lie on the form. And you should be ok.

Comment: @Donald Sorry about that—the background check has not been done yet. I haven't yet filled out the form but it seems I'll be doing that soon.

Comment: @siegfried- I would have to look at the SF86, but I believe the last time I read through it, being arrested and charged with a crime is the primary concern.  If the author is filling out a SF86, the background check involves interviews, so there will be an opportunity to answer any concerns the investigator might have.  *Which is the reason I suggested asking the police department about the incident so you better understand what happen.*

Comment: If the police finger-printed you, it is very likely that the record of the detention will easily show-up in FBI's radar. Whether it does or not, you not revealing it in any of their questioner can certainly be a red-flag against you if they find out later, and you may have to face closer scrutiny of the incident because of your attempt to conceal the fact.

Answer (score 5):

> If so, is this something I could explain?

If you are asked about this incident, then yes you should be able to explain the events the same as you have in this post.  You should have, however, already disclosed the incident in your application as usually there is a question "have you ever been arrested".  It is better to only have to explain what happened in the incident than to have to explain why you did not disclose the incident when asked.

Also, keep in mind that some companies will just reject you without explanation if they discover something they do not like in a background check.  There is not much you can do in that case other than continue your job search and make sure that you do not leave out any information that your application asks for.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This is admittedly pedantic, but I'm wondering about the use of the word "arrest" here. Here is a quote, from [this](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/justifies-arrest-probable-cause.html) website, about what legally qualifies as an arrest: "The U.S. Constitution's Fourth Amendment authorizes an arrest only if the police have probable cause to believe that a crime was committed and that the suspect did it." Does this qualify as an arrest under this definition?

Comment: @siegfried- I am not a lawyer but you admittedly assaulted an officer and were forcefully placed in handcuffs as a result, I would consider that an arrest but maybe the legal definition in your jurisdiction is different.

Comment: You are entirely correct here. I wasn't thinking of this as assault (it really was just a baby push—one hand with little force).

Comment: @sf02, not sure being placed in cuffs counts as being arrested.  They can be used as restraints for safety purposes, yours and the officer's safety.  Especially when someone is deemed to be (temporarily) out of control.

Comment: @siegfried- (I'm not a lawyer.) In many jurisdictions, "assault" is defined as "intentionally putting another person in reasonable apprehension of harmful or offensive contact." https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/assault  In other words, simply pushing a police officer is "assault". Unwanted touching by someone else is often taken as "assault". Even threatening to hit someone is "assault". "Battery" is the actual hit.

Comment: Arrest records are public information and can be gotten at low cost; if you are not sure if you were technically arrested or not it’s easy to find out.

Answer (score 1):

**They certainly know about the arrest, and the hospitalization for M.D.D.**

You need to assume they have the police report on this.  Be upfront about what happened.  You'll be asked to disclose any arrest or convictions, disclose this as an arrest before they run the official report.  **Make sure they know about this before getting the report!**  Also assume the company knows you were hospitalized for M.D.D.

> If so, is this something I could explain?

It sounds like you didn't do well under stress, which finance jobs are known for.  Hopefully they'll at least hear you side of the story.  If you're lucky you'll get the chance to explain what happened and convince them you won't exhibit bizarre, non-violent behavior towards your coworkers, or push the security guard.

Be ready with a good answer about changes you've made in your life to never get that stressed out again.  Focus on what's different in your life.  Take responsibility for your actions.

Also, be ready to accept this one mistake may have cost you this job.

Answer (score 0):

If you were detained, that's different from being arrested. If you weren't processed into the jail's intake system, you won't have a record that shows up in a criminal background check. You can always check the database and court records for the jurisdiction the incident took place and see if it shows up, and if it does, you should report it as a note somewhere on the background check form.

I was arrested as a minor after a fight in school, and got processed into the jail system, but it never shows up on my CBC. The only things that show up on my checks are a couple of traffic violations. In my case, the reason is that the state I was arrested in has a mandatory policy of not reporting juvenile offenses, so its like my arrest never happened.